# Why did most work items disappear from AzureDevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I created a testing environment with dummy work items including epics, features, user stories, issues, tasks, etc. - several work items of each type and all added to the same sprint called "internal testing".

[The work items are only shown in the "work items" page. I cannot see any work item in the sprints taskboard and backlog for the "internal testing" sprint. However, the backlog page does show an accurate count of the work items that should be part of this sprint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPMbL.png)

Can someone please help me fix this issue? Why are my work items not shown?

Comment: Are they in the appropriate area path?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have only one area and in this one area all work items are in the same path ("internal testing")

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? Just a remind of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are my work items not shown?

If you add issues as the child of user stories and tasks as the child of issues, the work items will disappear in the sprints.

[image]

Issues are not displayed on any backlog or board by default.
[image]
Please try the following workarounds:

1. Change the link type between work items from child to other types such as related.
2. If you are using an inherited process, you can add issues to iteration backlog:
   [image]

Then, add issues and tasks as child of user stories：

[image]

Result：

[image]

Comment: thank you for your very clear instructions, my problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, which was my case, is when your user story is assigned to a previous sprint, but has Tasks assigned to the current sprint. Creating a task for this user story on the sprint board will automatically assign the previous sprint to the new task.

E.g.
Test User Story (assigned to Sprint 16)
-- Task 1 (assigned to Sprint 17 - this will cause the task **as well as the User Story to appear in sprint 17**)
-- New Task 2 (will automatically adopt the User Story's sprint number)

1. "Test User Story" should not appear in sprint 17 but does due to the fact that Task 1 is assigned to sprint 17
2. Creating New Task 2 on the sprint board under Test User Story, will display for a second or so before disappearing. You'll find it in the backlog under the Test User Story, but with the User Story's sprint number instead of the current sprint.

Solution is to change the sprint of the new task, or in my case I moved the user story into the backlog and then make sure I only pull Tasks into the sprint to avoid this happening in future.